# Expanding and closing a list of files for my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created a file sharing website with PHP. The files are many and I want to narrow it and when a button is clicked, then it will expand. Please help me.

I tried using JavaScript to make the div of the files display hide or show when the button is clicked but it worked for only one file. I want all the files to hide at once and show when button is clicked.

Here is a sample code:

```
<?php

    // Displaying all files
    $files = scandir("../l100/core-for-all-100/sem-1/info-lit");

    for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++) {
        // Displaying links to download
?>

<div id="filesDiv" style="display: inline-flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <h3>
        <ul class="p-tag" id="files-list">

            <li class="files"> &nbsp;

                <div style="margin-left: -40px; margin-right: 20px; text-align: center; ">
                                
                <span style="background-image: url(../images/pdfimage.png);">

                <iframe src="../l100/dual-core-100/sem-1/info-lit/<?php echo $files[$a] ?>" type="application/pdf" download="false"></iframe>

                </span>

                <h4 style="text-decoration: none;"><br><?php echo $files[$a] ?> </h4>
      
                <a href="../l100/dual-core-100/sem-1/info-lit/<?php echo $files[$a] ?>" download>Download</a>
                               
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </h3>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Without your code, it's impossible for us to help you. Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: You added code, but it has no JS?

Comment: "*... it worked for only one file...*" - Keep in mind that values assigned to the `id` attribute needs to be unique, which is not the case in the code you've posted. You are generating multiple div's with the same id `filesDiv`

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to PHP? I would assume that the whole process of expanding and collapsing the list should be pure JS?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you rethink, due to abnormally heavy load you will be placing on a client and your server.

What you are proposing in general CSS terms is called an accordion, and does not need scripting just styling, to reveal the sub sections. Say an example like this.

[image]

You can see first one shows the potential problem with dynamic PDF contents, is that each needs a full download to the client, and not all clients have PDF viewers, nor powerful enough mobile devices to support that extra load in a single page. So will see blank boxes where the frames should be.

The second example is way too small to show contents, thus you will need each to be much larger.

Now to the crux of the reason as to why I suggest "Dont do it".
you seem to think setting `download = false` will avoid the server load of supporting each and every download. But it is a fact of PDF viewing that every single PDF on a HTML page (visible or not) needs 100% download to the  viewer.

What will happen is a client will get fed up waiting for all those downloads to choke their device and your server so busy with feeding all those thousands of PDF pages it will not have time for other clients, or use time sharing and all will be much slower.